# Populating a tool's field in Qgis Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to pouplate a tool's X and Y coordinates from a point file and I want to do this in the graphic modeler.
-But how do i connect the coordinates with the appropriate field in the Target X and Y coordinates of the tool, in this case when calculating the Upslope Area with a SAGA tool?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the TargetX and TargetY input of the slope algorithm are single values of you need to take these inputs from the vector layer?

If they are single numeric values you can add X and Y as numbers in the modeler and then link the values of the algorithm to them.

From the input parameters you can drag and drop the **number** parameter and give it default values.

[image]

Then you can link the values to the alorithm

[image]

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes @matteo, I have a vector layer containing several points where attributes for x and y is stored. I need to somehow iterate these points, take out the numbers for x and y and then run it through the Upslope Area tool. So, this actually includes a process of iteration, but do you have an idea of how to do this? And how did you manage to connect X and Y in your screendump?

Comment: @Andreas.. mmm you can do a batch job with processing.. however the input parameter of the saga algorithm are taken as single values not as vector field.. I think that you need to use python to do the magic..

Comment: Yeah, i was approaching the same conclusion of using python. You are absolutely right that the algorithm doesn't use vector field values and this is the obstacle. I'll try and circumvent it with scripting and will post the solution here if I somehow manage to finish it.